# Why is this map no an immersion at 0

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, submanifold

I wonder why the map $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R^2$ defined by $f(t)=(t^2, t^3)$ is not an immersion at 0. Isn't the derivative of $f$ is $(2t, 3t^2)$ which is injective? Thank you

Comment: $(2t,3t^2)|_{t=0}=(0,0)$

Comment: It's the differential of $f$ at the point, seen as a linear map $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^2$, that must be injective. Id est, the map $h\mapsto f'(0)h$ must be injective. You are confusing it with the map assigning to each point the differential differential of $f$ at that point, which may or may not be injective without changing the issue.